# how to add apostrophe in string

Tags: php, jquery

I had a value like this `$x = 'LA1,LA2,LA3,LA7';`

And I want to this value to be execute in my sql. 
I know it will return error because missing `''` in each id's. `example 'LA1','LA3','LA7'`
How to add this symbol so query can execute? Any idea?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN ("'.$x.'")';
```

Comment: Do you getting any error?

Comment: no error.. just not return any result.

Comment: do you have these ids in table?

Comment: yes.. the id's in the table. basically I need to retuen `$x` like this  `'LA1','LA3','LA7'`. but i had no idea how to do it

Comment: your ids in interger or in string?

Comment: try this :         $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN ('$x')";

Comment: You should probably use prepared statements instead, especially if that input isn't 100% controlled / can come from your users. [Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) giving you solutions to do this in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `explode` and `implode` ought to work

```
$x = 'LA1,LA2,LA3,LA7';
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN ("%s")', implode( '","', explode(',',$x) ) );
```

Comment: seem this method return the result. but what is `%s` mean?

Comment: It's a placeholder for the string replacement used by the likes of `printf`, `sprintf` `vsprintf` etc

Answer (score 1):

Ill suggest to put in array rather than keeping it in a string,

```
$variables = array('apple','orange','kiwi');
$variables = implode("','",$variables );

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN ('{$variables}')';
```

Comment: how to convert `$x = 'LA1,LA2,LA3,LA7';` into an array first?

Answer (score 0):

split it to array then add apostrophe

```
$x = 'LA1,LA2,LA3,LA7';
$arrayX = explode(',', $x);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN ("'.implode('",', $arrayX).'")';
```

Comment: I try this method but still return null

Answer (score -1):

You need `explode()` and `join()`

```
$x = 'LA1,LA2,LA3,LA7';
$x = explode(",", $x);
$x= join("', '", $x);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id IN ('$x')";
```

Comment: @YasinPatel we can use explode and join